# CartThrob billing fields not sending to PayPal

Tags: ee2, cartthrob, paypal-express-checkout

I've got CartThrob using PayPal (Express) running, along with Profile:Edit. On the checkout page, the billing & shipping fields are getting pre-populated correctly using CT's [customer_info](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/customer_info/) tag.

However, when the checkout button is hit (which redirects you to PayPal for payment), the only fields that get pre-populated on the *PayPal page* are the first and last names. We definitely don't want the customer to have to fill that info out *again*.

Code can be seen [here](http://cl.ly/OXQZ).

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. :/

Comment: Mmm, something doesn't sound right. Whenever I've used CT with PayPal, there are no fields to fill out info when you get to PayPal; all you have to do is log in or choose to pay by credit card where you then enter your card details.

Comment: Hm, I'll need to double-check settings and code then.

Comment: Heh, I'm just a dunce. Was expecting something different for some reason. Maybe I was confusing PayPal Express with Pro.